# Retrieve user's Outlook status

Tags: c#, vbscript, outlook-2010

I found VBScript code to retrieve a user's Outlook status and display in a list box. I need it to be C# and there are no conversion tools online:

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set objRecipient = objNameSpace.CreateRecipient("kenmyer")
strFreeBusyData = objRecipient.FreeBusy(#11/11/2014#, 60)

dtmStartDate = #11/11/2014#

For i = 1 to Len(strFreeBusyData) Step 24 
    Wscript.Echo dtmStartDate
    strDay = Mid(strFreeBusyData, i, 24)

    For x = 1 to 12
        If x = 1 Then
            strTime = "12 AM: "
        Else
            strTime = x - 1 & " AM: "
        End If 

        intFreeBusy = Mid(strDay, x, 1)
        If intFreeBusy = 1 Then
            strFreeBusy = "Busy"
        Else
            strFreeBusy = "Free"
        End If

        Wscript.Echo strTime & strFreeBusy
    Next

    For x = 13 to 24
        If x = 13 Then
            strTime = "12 PM: "
        Else
            strTime = x - 13 & " PM: "
        End If 

        intFreeBusy = Mid(strDay, x, 1)
        If intFreeBusy = 1 Then
            strFreeBusy = "Busy"
        Else
            strFreeBusy = "Free"
        End If

        Wscript.Echo strTime & strFreeBusy
    Next

    Wscript.Echo
    dtmStartDate = dtmStartDate + 1

    If dtmStartDate > #11/12/2014# Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

The end result would look like this in my C# application under the appointments list box:

```
11/11/2014
8 AM: Free
9 AM: Free
10 AM: Free
11 AM: Free
12 PM: Free
1 PM: Free
2 PM: Free
3 PM: Free
4 PM: Free
5 PM: Busy
6 PM: Free
```

What I have so far:

```
private void userschedule()
{
    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace ns = oApp.Application.Session;

    Outlook.Recipient recipient = ns.CreateRecipient(username.Text);

    DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;

    string freeBusy = recipient.AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy(datetime, 60, true);

    string status = freeBusy.Substring(0, 1);

    textBox1.Text = status;
}
```

How can I convert this to C#? The other set of code is similar:

```
For i = 1 to Len(strFreeBusyData) Step 24 
    Wscript.Echo dtmStartDate
    strDay = Mid(strFreeBusyData, i, 24)

    For x = 1 to 12
        If x = 1 Then
            strTime = "12 AM: "
        Else
            strTime = x - 1 & " AM: "
        End If 

        intFreeBusy = Mid(strDay, x, 1)
        If intFreeBusy = 1 Then
            strFreeBusy = "Busy"
        Else
            strFreeBusy = "Free"
        End If

        Wscript.Echo strTime & strFreeBusy
    Next
```

**Newly Edited Code ( Final Answer to my Question)**

```
private void userstatus()
{
    {
        {
            Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace ns = oApp.Application.Session;
            Outlook.Recipient recipient = ns.CreateRecipient(username.Text);
            DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now; // gets current date and time
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today; //gets todays date
            startDate.AddHours(8); //Skip to 8 am
            string freeBusy = recipient.AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy(startDate, 60, true);
            textBox1.Text = freeBusy;

            foreach (char c in freeBusy) //iteration process
            {
                if (startDate.Hour == 0) //start at 12 AM
                    Contacts.Items.Add(startDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
                if (8 <= startDate.Hour && startDate.Hour <= 18) // 8AM to 6PM inclusive
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(
                        String.Format(
                            "{0}: {1}",
                            startDate.ToString("hh tt"),
                            c == '0' ? "Free" : "Busy"));
                }
                startDate = startDate.AddHours(1);
                if (startDate.Date > DateTime.Today)
                    break; // stop once we get to tomorrow.
            }
        }
    }
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userstatus();
    }
```

The `freeBusy` string looks like this for the user I am getting the free/busy status for.

I got the below by doing this:

```
string freeBusy = recipient.AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy(datetime, 60, true);
textBox1.Text = freeBusy;
```

> 000000002200000000000000000000002200000000000000333333333333333333333333000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000001100000000000000002000001000000000000000002000000000000000000000002022200000000000000000002000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000333333333333333333333333000000002001101000000000000000002000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000001100000000000000002000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000002020000000000000000000002000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000001100000000000000002000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000002000000000000000

Comment: If you've made any attempt at this you should post it, along with specifics about which parts you don't understand.

Comment: To get started you'll need to reference `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` COM library.

Comment: @juharr i edited this and added what i tried but the logic starting from for is really confusing me.

Comment: @juharr i have all these referenced Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.RecurrencePattern recurrencePattern;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace oNS;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder oCalendar;Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items oItems;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppt;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application _OutlookApplication;

Comment: Basically that for loop is splitting the `strFreeBusyData` string up into chucks of 24 characters.  It would literally translate to `for(int i = 1; i <= strFreeBusyData.Length; i += 24)` but you'd probably want to go with a zero based approach in C#.

Comment: @juharr 24 chunks equal to 24 hrs but your saying use 0 so i would get busy or free for that moment am i correct??

Comment: It looks like `GetFreeBusy` will return a string of 1's and 0's indicating availability for each hour of a given day.  But you should be able to see exactly what it returns by playing with the code you have so far.

Comment: Check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recipient.freebusy(v=office.15).aspx), Turns out it will return a string of 1's and 0's for a month worth of days, that's why it is breaking the string up into chucks of 24.

Comment: See my answer as to why you should start at 0 in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following for loop and logic in VBScript

```
For i = 1 to Len(strFreeBusyData) Step 24 
    Wscript.Echo dtmStartDate
    strDay = Mid(strFreeBusyData, i, 24)
    ...
Next
```

would be equivalent to the following in C#

```
for(int i = 0; i < strFreeBusyData.Length; i+= 24)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dtmStartDate);
    var strDay = strFreeBusyData.Substring(i, 24);
    ...   
}
```

One big difference between VBScript and C# is that VBScript tends to be 1 - based when dealing with strings, whereas C# is 0 based.  Specifically the `Mid` function's first parameter wants an index into the string that is 1-based (1 would mean start at the first character) whereas `string.Substring`s first parameter should be 0-based (0 would mean start at the first character).

**EDIT**

After sleeping on it a better way of dealing with this in C# would be the following.

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today;
string freeBusy = recipient.AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy(datetime, 60, true);
foreach(char c in freeBusy)
{
    if(startDate.Hour == 0)
        Console.WriteLine(startDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    Console.WriteLine(
        "{0}: {1}",
        startDate.ToString("hh tt"),
        c == '1' ? "Busy" : "Free");
    startDate = startDate.AddHours(1);
}
```

This will get a `DateTime` that has today's date, but a time of 12 am.  Then as you iterate over each character in the `freeBusy` string you will output the `startDate` formatted as dd/MM/yyyy when the hour is 0 or 12 am.  Then you write out the hour in 12 hour time (hh) and the AM/PM designator (tt) and the word Busy if the character is "1" or Free otherwise.  Then increment the `startDate` by one hour.  This avoids the unnecessary inner for loops that the VBScript code has.

**EDIT**

Based on your updated code you should change this

```
listBox1.Items.Add("{0}: {1}") ;
listBox1.Items.Add(startDate.ToString("hh tt") + " " + (c == '1' ? "Busy" : "Free"));
listBox1.Items.Add(c == '1' ? "Busy" : "Free");
startDate.AddHours(1);
```

to this

```
listBox1.Items.Add(
    string.Format(
        "{0}: {1}", 
        startDate.ToString("hh tt"),
        c == '1' ? "Busy" : "Free");
startDate = startDate.AddHours(1);
```

The "{0}: {1}" is for formatting and `Console.WriteLine` has an overload that takes a format string.  The date wasn't changing because `DateTime` is immuteable and you have to capture the return value of `AddHours`, that was my bad.

**Edit**

Here's code that will only show items for today and only between 8am and 6pm

```
foreach (char c in freeBusy) //iteration process
{
    if (startDate.Hour == 0 ) //start at 12 AM
        Contacts.Items.Add(startDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    if(8 <= startDate.Hour && startDate.Hour <= 18) // 8AM to 6PM inclusive
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(
            String.Format(
            "{0}: {1}", 
            startDate.ToString("hh tt"),
            c == '1' ? "Busy" : "Free"));
    }

    startDate = startDate.AddHours(1);
    if(startDate.Date > DateTime.Today)
        break; // stop once we get to tomorrow.
}
```

You can optimize this to break after you hit 6PM if you want.  It could also be shortened to the following

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today; //gets todays date
string freeBusy = recipient.AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy(datetime, 60, true);
Contacts.Items.Add(startDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")); 
startDate = startDate.AddHours(8); //Skip to 8 am
foreach (char c in freeBusy.Skip(8).Take(11)) // skip to 8AM and only go to 6PM
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(
        String.Format(
            "{0}: {1}", 
            startDate.ToString("hh tt"),
            c == '0' ? "Free" : "Busy"));

    startDate = startDate.AddHours(1);
}
```

**EDIT**

Changed

```
c == '1' ? "Busy" : "Free"
```

to

```
c == '0' ? "Free" : "Busy"
```

Comment: Arrays in VBScript are zero-based. I think you're confusing it with VBA here.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Right, I think I was actually thinking of other indexed objects from a 3rd party library that started at 1.  The trick in VBScript with arrays is that the UBound function gives you the last index and you have to add 1 to get the length.  And when you create an array you give it the size - 1.

Comment: @juharr my listbox is getting filled with these values {0}:{1} 12 AM Free, {0}:{1} 12 AM Free, {0}:{1} 12 AM Free,{0}:{1} 12 AM Free it does not seem to iterate the time and the free does not change to busy and the user i am searching this for is suppose to be busy at the moment. I have the screenshot available here [link](http://imgur.com/OHvbWvA) but i really appreciate your help so far i know we are really close to fixing this... So the code is as follows based on your suggestions i added it to the above question....

Comment: See my update, I wasn't assigning the result of `AddHours` back to `startDate`.

Comment: @juharr now it is iterating perfectly but the issue is i dont want to view users status for the future, i want to only see his/her free or busy status from 8AM to 6pm normal working hours for today. like in my question  firstline the date then 8am to 6pm with free or busy next to them, so my question is what do i set the startDate.hour to?? and how would i tell the iteration process to stop when it is 6pm?? rest all looks good.

Comment: Just add `if(8 <= startDate.Hour && startDate.Hour <= 18)` around the code that adds the values to `listBox1` and add a `if(startDate.Date > DateTime.Today) break;` after the `AddHours` call.

Comment: @HackGod555 See my update for how to skip to 8AM and stop at 6PM on the same day.

Comment: @juharr we are getting really close bud this -> [link](http://imgur.com/goM7RqU) shows the current result however i am still getting 12 AM to 9 AM but i need 8 AM to 6 PM. the revised code is added to my question.

Comment: @HackGod555 I made the same mistake again.  It should be `startDate = startDate.AddHours(8);`

Comment: @HackGod555 Also I think it needs to be `Take(11)` instead of `Take(10)` to get up to 6PM.

Comment: @juharr you were right the first time and startDate = startDate.AddHours(1); is correct because we are adding an hour to the time. it was a mistake on my part but we are very close bud this -> [link](http://imgur.com/jJSgXUu) the user i am selecting the status for was busy from 10 Am to 11 AM today but it shows as FREE but has to be BUSY how come???

Comment: @HackGod555 what does the `freeBusy` string look like?

Comment: @juharr string freeBusy = recipient.AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy(datetime, 60, true);

Comment: @HackGod555 No, I mean the actually value that `freeBusy` is being set to when you run the code.  It should start with "0000000000110000000...." if the 10am and 11am hours are busy.

Comment: @HackGod555 It might be because you are passing `dateTime` instead of `startDate` to `GetFreeBusy` because `dataTime` would have the current time, say 3PM and if it starts at the time given then it might be skipping the 12AM to 2PM hours.  `startDate` has the current date, but the time set to 12AM, which would work with the rest of the code.  If you need to start with the current time then you'll have to factor that into the rest of the solution.

Comment: @juharr i had a dumb moment there :), i posed the string result in my question for this particular user i couldn't post it here it said i was some characters too long.

Comment: @juharr i changed it to  string freeBusy = recipient.AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy(startDate, 60, true); but the result is still the same

Comment: @HackGod555 OK, one issue is that we need to associate '0' with Free and anything else as Busy.  But that string seems to show 8 and 9 am as busy.

Comment: FYI heres a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.getfreebusy(v=office.15).aspx) that describes what the various values 0-3 mean.

Comment: @HackGod555 regarding what seems to be a 2 hour time shift, is it possible that the exchange server is in a different timezone?

Comment: @juharr hey bud look at the pic in this -> [link](http://imgur.com/I84A6jl) for a better understanding of what i am talking about so the ones i high lighted are suppose to be busy right even when you take the time zone in to consideration this particular user says she is busy from time now being 2.26pm to 5.30pm so that what i was wondering??

Comment: @HackGod555 Did you see the last edit I made to my answer?  That should show 8am and 9am as busy for the string you posted.  Now if it's suppose to be 10am and 11am then my best guest is that there is a time zone shift of 2 hours.

Comment: @juharr i am actually using the first version of your edited code  if (startDate.Hour == 0 ) //start at 12 AM
        Contacts.Items.Add(startDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    if(8 <= startDate.Hour && startDate.Hour <= 18) // 8AM to 6PM inclusive i am not able to use the shortened version because .skip .take are not working in my code, i am using visual studio 2008 and outlook 2010. i am referencing System.Linq but the skip and take methods are not working for me, can you please show me the same thing in the first version???

Comment: @juharr one word for you AWESOME!!!!, Really appreciate all your help bud, and the exchange server was in the same time zone so didnt have to mess with that either. Everything WorKs :) i would vote you up all the way but i only have 7 reputations and i need 15 :( but once i have 15 reputations i will come back and vote this up and your really going to help alot of people with this answer.

Comment: @juharr also none of my business but i really think you should write a book about integrating c# with outlook and other technologies because the way you explained the concept between vb script and c# the 0 and 1 simply amazing and look at me i had no clue what i was doing and now im done with my project with your help :) keep up the good work bud.